# Use promises in nested maps with $q.all()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, q

I am trying to figure out what data-structure of promises I can use in `$q.all()` function. I know that I can give it an array of promises and a map of promises, but can I give it an aribitrary depth map as well? eg can I do something like:

```
var map = {};
map["A"] = {};
map["A"]["B"] = MyService.getPromise();

$q.all(map).then(function(resultMap){
    // does resultMap match the structure of the input map?
    console.debug(resultMap["A"]["B"])
})
```

And if I can't, what is the suggested way to do something like this? I would like to know the original level inside the map of my resulting data.

Comment: No you can't pass an arbitrary object to it. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

For me this looks pretty simple and works:

```
 var promises = [];

 promises.push(MyService.getPromise().then(function(result) {
    map["A"]["B"] = result;
 }));

 promises.push(MyService.getPromise().then(function(result) {
    map["A"]["C"] = result;
 }));

...

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
  // map is initialized here
})
```

Comment: how do you know that the result is for C or B ?